# React Data Fetching & rerenders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In my React App I want to fetch data from DB every 5 seconds and display it.
The data is an array of objects:
It's an array of "station"s each station has these properties:

1. Name
2. status = Run/Hold
3. Update Time

I'm displaying all the stations and their info and also displaying a toolbar on the top that is counting the number of stations based on their status (e.g. "Running: 10, Holding: 20")

the station are in a component called "displayStations"
To achieve it I'm using a state in the displayStations that is holding the array of objects and fetches it.
Now the problem is that if I'm updating the state of the displayStations with the new array all the stations under it will get rerendered but I want only the changed stations to be rerenderd. what is the best approach on solving it?

- Code:

```
function DisplayStations() {
  const [stationsData, setStationsData] = useState([]);

.
.
.

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchStationsData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`/stationsInfo`);
      const data = await response.json();
      setStationsData(data);
      handleStationsDataChange();
    };
    fetchStationsData();
    const fetchInterval = setInterval(() => {
      fetchStationsData();
    }, intervalTime * 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(fetchInterval);
    };
  });
.
.
.
return (
    <Box>
      {stationsData.map((stationsDataObj) => {
        return <Station key={stationsDataObj['Name']} stationData={stationsDataObj} />;
      })}
    </Box>
  );
}




function Station({ stationData }) {
return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {stationData['Name']}
      </div>
      <div>
        {stationData['Status']}
      </div>
      <div>
        {stationData['updateTime']}
      </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: did you mean that you want to add the new stations array to the previous one?? or i got it wrong?

Comment: You might be looking for memo. https://react.dev/reference/react/memo

Comment: With a request every five seconds you might want to consider a [socket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) or, perhaps possibly more useful, [server sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events).

Comment: @GhadeerAhmad you got it wrong mate, it is the same array but may have changes in the properties of the objects(stations) inside of it, or with new added objects (stations)

Comment: i think you have to use useMemo as @CodeThing mentioned above, because react do rerender the whole component on each change so when you use memo it will only rerender when there is new value otherwise it won't rerender

Comment: @GhadeerAhmad but there will always be a new value because each time it is a new Array (may have the same values but it is a different pointer)

Comment: Are you running to some sort of performance issue? If not rendering only changed stations seems like a optimisation you could forget about. @OmerMesser

Comment: @OmerMesser i think you will get better explaination about this hook from this article, https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-the-usememo-hook-in-react

Comment: @Andy I'm not running into performance issues yet becuase it is a small scale. I just want to understand the proper way to solve it. I do want to render only changed stations but don't know what's the best approach

Comment: @GhadeerAhmad I was referring to React.memo. useMemo is different thing.

Comment: @OmerMesser Yes this will be different value for arrays but you can use second parameter of memo for props comparison. For instance, you can compare if the names are equal or not. Here is Reference article: https://dmitripavlutin.com/use-react-memo-wisely/

Comment: is stationsDataObj['Name'] unique? seems like it shouldnt be.  you need a unique value for the key.  in this case maybe its name + index, not sure.  if its not unique ur gonna get a re-render of everything in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you can make use of React.memo HOC to wrap your component so that it doesn't re-render when the props are not changed.

By default it does shallow comparison. To compare if the props are really changed you can pass function as second parameter for props comparison.

You can do something like below.

```
import { memo } from "react";

const Station = ({ stationData }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{stationData["Name"]}</div>
      <div>{stationData["Status"]}</div>
      <div>{stationData["updateTime"]}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

function propsAreEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  return prevProps.Name === nextProps.Name 
    && prevProps.Status === prevProps.Status
    && prevProps.updateTime === prevProps.updateTime;
}

export default memo(Station, propsAreEqual);
```

Comment: why would you need to do this if the key is already name?

Comment: @terpinmd The comparison function could check anything. Not just name. You could check any value inside your object. Or combination of values inside objects. The goal is to determine the prev thing and current thing is same.

Comment: yes I get that it could check anything, but name would be the same as what he has with key now  <Station key={stationsDataObj['Name']}

Comment: It doesn't necessary the same. Let's say in the first render you get three object with Name as St1, St2, St3. In the next render after api call you might get different list and that's what we are checking here.

Comment: we will have to agree to disagree.  im not gonna down-vote, but 'key' is how lists know not to re-render

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you may have to use as:

```
const fetchStationsData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`/stationsInfo`);
      const data = await response.json();
      setStationsData(data);
      handleStationsDataChange();
    };
useEffect(() => {
    fetchStationsData();
    const fetchInterval = setInterval(() => {
      fetchStationsData();
    }, intervalTime * 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(fetchInterval);
    };
  },[]); //here this will work as to display the content one
```

May this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in this approach the fetching will occur only at the first render. am i Wrong?

Comment: it renders at once. Have a try

Answer (score 0):

You can tell React to skip applying an effect if certain values haven’t changed between re-renders. To do so, pass an array as an optional second argument to useEffect.

Example:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
}, [count]); // Only re-run the effect if count changes
```

Source: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html